# How can I merge one dataframe (right) into another empty dataframe (left) using the datetime index of the left and a datetime column in the right?

Tags: python, pandas, merge

When merging one dataframe into an empty one, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# create an empty dataframe with a datetime index
df_main = pd.DataFrame(columns=[], index=pd.to_datetime([]))
df_main.index.name = 'datetime'

# now create a few columns of data
# a numbers column and a datetime column
utc_timestamp = [
    '2019-02-03 14:00:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:01:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:02:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:03:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:04:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:05:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:06:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:07:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:08:00+00',
    '2019-02-03 14:09:00+00',
]
data = np.arange(len(utc_timestamp)) * 2 + 1

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['data1'])
df.loc[:, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(utc_timestamp, utc=True)
.
.
.

# merge the right dataframe into the empty left dataframe
df_main = df_main.merge(df,
                        how='outer',
                        left_index=True,
                        right_on='datetime')
```

Here is the right dataframe:

```
    data1 data1flag                  datetime
0     1.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:00:00+00:00
1     3.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:01:00+00:00
2  9999.0        M2 2019-02-03 14:02:00+00:00
3     7.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:03:00+00:00
4     9.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:04:00+00:00
5    11.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:05:00+00:00
6    13.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:06:00+00:00
7    15.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:07:00+00:00
8    17.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:08:00+00:00
9    19.0        V0 2019-02-03 14:09:00+00:00
```

Here is the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ...
>
> TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Index)

I have looked at every question and every tutorial.  I simply want to be able to repeatedly merge a new dataframe into the main one.  I cannot merge using the datetime column in any way.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: bernski, welcome to stackoverflow. I have run your code on pandas 0.25.3 and python 3.6 and don't any errors. What are the versions you are using? By the way, I have edited your code according to [python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I am using python: 3.6.5.final.0 and pandas 0.23.0, using Spyder 3.28 on Anaconda, which may account for the discrepancy.  I'll update pandas and try again.

Comment: Updating pandas did the trick!  Many thanks!